# Paging and Logical and Physical Addresses

Tags: paging

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Since the page # is 22 bits and the offset is 10 bits, how can we determine what is referenced?  Logical 4870 maps to page #4 but how do go about calculating the rest?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already know how to split up the address into its page and offset. The page table allows you to convert between physical and logical pages. You then just need to reassemble the converted page and original offset back into an address.

Comment: So logical 4870 would be page 4 offset 51 => (51*1+4) = physical 55?

Comment: How do you begin breaking down logical 33214?

Comment: @Latoya I thought you knew why 4870 was in page 4. It is in page 4 because 4870 = (4 << 10) + 774, so the offset is 774. (The offset is always less than 1 << 10 because that would be a new page.)